# Create an event only when contact approval status is approved

Tags: visualforce, validation-rule

I want to display an error message when a user tries to create an event for a contact that is not approved. Is it possible to do this with a visualforce page?

Comment: Im using visualforcepage to display error message

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's no need to replace a native page with Visualforce to achieve this!  (Always avoid replacing native pages when you can.)

Instead, you can use a trigger to see whether the associated Contact is approved.  If it isn't, use the addError method to prevent the record from being saved.

If you add the error to the field you're interested in -- in this case the "Name" (WhoId) field -- the user will see [a nice, pretty error message](https://albasfdc.com/2017/04/17/demystifying-adderror/) on the *native* Event creation page, just below that field.

In your trigger, get the record the Event's WhoId points to.  This field is polymorphic -- it could point to a Contact *or* a Lead record -- so we'll need to make sure we're only looking at the Contact records' approval status field. (...unless you want to perform the same check for Leads, that is.)

```
if(eventRecord.WhoId.getSObjectType() == Contact.sObjectType){
    //Check the Contact's approval status
    if(eventRecord.WhoId.Status__c != 'Approved'){

        // If the Contact isn't approved, attach an error to the Name (WhoId) field
        eventRecord.WhoId.addError('This contact has not been approved.');

    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks it is working.But the requirement is when i click new event button it should show a pop alert in visualforcepage saying that contact is not approved ,since javascript doesnt support in lightning mode.

Comment: I hv a question user will create event in Account without creating contacts.When i try to add .It is throwing Null pointer exception.I added condition WhoIld!=null still its throwing error.

Answer (score 1):

You should handle this use case with the use of recordtype.

Let's say, before approval create a recordtype `IntialContactType` and assign a page layout where in the Activity related list, do not expose `New` button, so user will not able to create any event before approval.

Create a separate reccortype `PostApproval` and assign a separate page layout where you will expose `New` event button, so after approval user can create event.

In the approval final action, update Contact's recordtype to `PostApproval` by field update functionality.

*So, only by changing the recordtype your use case can be solved, no need to use trigger or visualforce.*

Comment: Interesting solution.  I like it!   The only reason I might go with a trigger in this case -- and I hate writing code when I don't have to -- is because an event could still be created, referencing an unapproved contact, from someplace besides the contact record page.  (Perhaps from a Lightning action, or the Chatter feed, or etc.)

Comment: You can put a validation rule to restrict creation from other sources. Configuration is better than customization.

Comment: Which answer solves your purpose is not clear

Comment: @SantanuBoral -- I'm curious about the validation rule part.  How are you seeing that implemented?  It's a cool idea -- and, yes, always better to go with native than to customize!

Answer (score -1):

You can do like this in vf page -

```
<apex:pageMessages id="showmsg"></apex:pageMessages>
<apex:commandButton value="Update" action="{!save}" style="width:90px" rerender="showmsg"/>
```

And in apex class -

```
Contact con;
public void save(){
if(con.Status != 'Approved')
ApexPages.addMessage(new ApexPages.Message(ApexPages.severity.Error,'You can not create event bcoz contact status is not approved.'));
}
```